# 'object' is not subscriptable in 2d python list

Tags: python, nested-lists

> Message='SodokuGame' object is not subscriptable
>   Source=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\python\Soduku\Soduku\Soduku.py
>   StackTrace:    File
>   "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\python\Soduku\Soduku\Soduku.py", line 31, in
>   fillArray
>       if currentArray[x][y].value == 0:
>
> File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\python\Soduku\Soduku\Soduku.py", line 110,
>   in **init**
>       game.fillArray(game.matrix, 0, 0, game.newPool)    File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\python\Soduku\Soduku\Soduku.py", line 113, in
>   
>       Run()

I am trying my own project and ran into an issue. To begin I have my cell class. My goal is to test the data in the `Cell` and run code dependent on the results but on runtime I run into the error above.

```
class Cell:
    value = 0
    def __getitem__(self):
        return self.value
    def __setitem__(newVal, self):
        self.value = newVal
```

This is how I defined and tried to add my list

```
class SodokuGame:

    matrix = []
    for i in range(9):
        arr = []
        for j in range(9):
            arr.append(Cell())
        matrix.append(arr)

    def fillArray(currentArray, x, y, pool, self):
        if currentArray[x][y].value == 0:
            print("fillArray loop") #unimportant context code from here on
            poolNum = randint(0, pool.length)
            if testNumber(pool[poolNum]):
                currentArray[x][y]= pool.pop(pool[poolNum])
                print(poolNum)
```

My first assumption was that the array was being filled incorrectly to fail the if statement but that is not the issue. I believe the issue is during the

```
if currentArray[x][y].value == 0:
```

somehow even when I instantiated all nodes at an (x,y) it is still giving me an error as if I'm comparing a `SodukuGame` object to 0.

How it is called originally:

```
class Run:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Run")
        game = SodokuGame()
        game.printGrid()
        game.fillArray(game.matrix, 0, 0, game.newPool)
        game.printGrid()
Run()
```

Notes: I don't think it's relevant to the question but this function's intention is to check to see if the current cell is empty(=0), and if not, it will attempt to fill the cell and recursively run the function again moving over one cell until the structure is full.

I've tried implementing methods in the `Cell` class to workaround this, including adding a `__getitem__` function, a native `getInfo` function, and even tried to use a `isZero` boolean function but all of these result in the same error. This is not for homework.

Comment: Please give us the full traceback (copy&paste). I'm pretty sure that the error message is not "object is not scriptable"

Comment: @Matthias added. my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Justin. There are a few problems here, but the first one is that you aren't starting your instance methods with `self`. Python is still treating those variables like self, which is why you're getting the error "SodokuGame is not subscriptable". It's not subscripting the matrix you're passing in; it's subscripting the instantiated object of the `SodokuGame` class itself.

This is what the SodokuGame class's `fillArray` method should look like

```
class SodokuGame:
    def fillArray(self, currentArray, x, y, pool):
      if currentArray[x][y].value == 0:
        # do stuff
```

You'll notice I put `self` up front in the argument list, which you'll always need to do. Python doesn't listen to where you put `self`, because you can technically name it whatever you want (you shouldn't, but you can). It's just always the first argument in an instance method.

After this you'll run into problems with Cell. You're implementing `__getitem__`, but Cell doesn't have an array to subscript. If you really want to subscript it, but always return the same value for some reason, you need to implement the method correctly (same goes for `__setitem__`):

```
class Cell:
    value = 0
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.value
    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.value = value
```

if you don't actually want to subscript `Cell`, i.e. you don't want to do

```
c = Cell()
c[247321] = 2
# 247321 can literally be anything; 'turkey', 12, 32.1, etc.
# that is what item is in the __getitem__ and __setitem__ methods, and
# you're not using that argument in the implementations
```

you should probably not utilize `__getitem__`, but rather do something like:

```
class Cell:
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

but your method of accessing the property directly with `.value` also works.

Comment: I could’ve stared at the code for hours and not realized self had had to be in a specific place. I appreciate the help.